# Login page still says site is in private beta

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

The public beta was supposed to start a few minutes ago, but the login page still says the site is in private beta for another day.

[image: The login page, which says "Warning: this site is currently in private beta for 1 more day.]

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** It's now public, of course.

I see I'm not the only one trying to catch the moment. :)

The [Area 51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7526/japanese-language-usage) says that the public beta is about to begin shortly.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's public now; the Area 51 e-mail went out and you can get to the homepage without logging in